# How to write test results and data in the Excel File with EaseTech, Selenium, java

Tags: java, excel, selenium, webdriver

```
@RunWith(DataDrivenTestRunner.class)
@DataLoader(filePaths = { "C:/eclipse/backendUserRegistration.xls" } , writeData=false)

public class UserLimitationPerCountryAndOperatorTest extends SeamlessBaseTest{

@Test
public void testLimitOfUsersOnOperators(@Param(name="country")String country ,
                                        @Param(name="limitation")String limitation) {
    OMBEBasePage basePage = loginOMBE();
    NewUserRegistrationPage registrationPage = basePage.goToNewUserRegistrationPage();
    registrationPage.createNewUser(country, "Noxwin");
    String account = registrationPage.getAccountCreatedConfirmationMessage();
    assertTrue(account.contains(" created"));
    String createdUser = account.split(" ")[0];
    System.out.println(createdUser);
    UserSearchPage userSearchPage = basePage.goToUserSearchPage();
    userSearchPage.searchByUserName(createdUser);
    String userLocalLimit = userSearchPage.getUserGeneralLocalLimit();
    assertEquals(limitation, userLocalLimit);
    userSearchPage.goToMyProfileTab();
    String userCountry = userSearchPage.countryOfUser();
    assertEquals(" "+country, userCountry);
}

@After
public void logoutAfterTest() {
    OMBEBasePage basePage = new OMBEBasePage(driver);
    basePage.logoutOMBE();
}
```

}

This is the test that I've written and it works fine, what I would like to do now, is to write in the Excel file the `createdUser` on one column and the test result on another column.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this simple scenario I guess creating CSV file and importing it to the Excel would do the job for you. So just write

```
try {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("testResult.csv");
    writer.append(createdUser);
    writer.append(',');
    writer.append(testResult); //whatever String this is
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
catch (IOException ex) {
    //handle exception somehow    
}
```

And than import `testResult.csv` into the Excel, it should give you a sheet with two columns - created user and test result.

In case you will have some complex scenarios, I recommend you using [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) library.

Comment: I tried your solution and it indeed writes in the CSV, but it overrides  previous data.(the xls file that I use has 5 parameters and the test runs them all, one by one), and about the test result, I was wondering if it can automatically write test result as in Passed/Failed/Error. Thanks

Comment: Of course you can do that, simple solution is to have a `count` variable in your test class which will increment with each test execution. Than you can save your files like `new FileWriter("testResult" + count + "1.csv");`. But maybe you will figure out something better :)

Comment: And for the second question, this depends if you use TestNG or JUnit, you need to setup some listener which will be called after the test is finished and it will append the result into your file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am using JUnit.